# How can i can find the most frequently applications used by a user in Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there any way that i can find the most frequently applications used by a user in Linux? In Windows you can read this information from registry.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so it's off-topic here. It may be more appropriate on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Just make sure you read over their help center to be sure before you post it there, and delete this question here if you do so. We don't want the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites at the same time.

Comment: The category for this question is Linux is not a programming question. Why it should be a programming question it is a question about Linux and the category is correctly.

Comment: The entire Stack Overflow site is about programming, and every question asked needs to relate to programming, regardless of the [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) used. You're asking about how to use an operating system, which is not a programming question. The [tag:linux] tag should be used for questions about the Linux API, Linux kernel programming, writing Linux-compatible programs, etc, **not** about how to *use* Linux. Read this: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that [accounting is turned on](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/):

`chkconfig psacct on && /etc/init.d/psacct start`

...and then get summary info with [`sa`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sa). Look at examples [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tag/sa-command) or [here](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools).

My own experience is that the most frequent command in the account is a shell.

Comment: On CentOS don't work, i have no file psacct in/etc/init.d and the psacct is installed.

Comment: Look, I have used it on RHEL 6 and CentOS is just a free version of it. If it does not start this way start it like `service psacct start` (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Services.html). As soon as accounting is running  it you can use `sa` and get your info.